# Failed to get two rows within a parent row bootstrap 4 and VueJs

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I am creating a component with VueJs and Boostrap4, in which I want to obtain a design similar to this with the classes offered by bootstrap

Reading the documentation, bootstrap offers customized classes h-75 and h-25 with what I thought would be sufficient but I do not get the desired result

```js
Vue.component('listcontent', {
  template: '<div class="w-100 h-75 bg-info">ds</div>'
})

Vue.component('datashared', {
  template: ' <div class="w-100 h-25 bg-primary">dsadsa</div>'
})


Vue.component('maincomponent', {
  template: `<div class="container h-100" >
        <div class="row h-100">
            <div class="col-md-5 h-100 border">
                <listcontent></listcontent>
                <datashared/></datashared>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>`
})

new Vue({ el: '#app'});
```

```css
html,body {
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <maincomponent></maincomponent>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I achieve the desired result?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add 100% height  to the id app element too

```
html,
body,
#app {
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

```js
Vue.component('listcontent', {
  template: '<div class="w-100 h-75 bg-info">ds</div>'
})

Vue.component('datashared', {
  template: ' <div class="w-100 h-25 bg-primary">dsadsa</div>'
})


Vue.component('maincomponent', {
  template: `<div class="container h-100" >
        <div class="row h-100">
            <div class="col-md-5 h-100 border">
                <listcontent></listcontent>
                <datashared/></datashared>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>`
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#app {
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <maincomponent></maincomponent>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, does this mean that I should always add height: 100% to the root element of vuejs? . in this case it is #app, but it could have had another identifier. because the w-75 classes work without adding width: 100%

Comment: block level elements take 100% width of browser by default, so w-75 works. But height doesn't work in this way. You have to set the height of all the ancestor tags as 100% if you want to use h-75 and h-25 classes.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, it worked perfectly. regards

Answer (score 1):

`h-100`'s height:100% takes the height of it's parent. Since you don't have parent you need to give a fix height. I wrapped the entire HTML with a `div` and set 100vh of height which is window height.

> Since I am not familiar with `vue` I used to make this as HTML. Place
>   your components as you want.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div style="height:100vh">
<div class="container h-100">
  <div class="row h-100">
    <div class="col-md-5 h-100 border">
      <div class="w-100 h-75 bg-info">ds</div>
      <div class="w-100 h-25 bg-primary">dsadsa</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```